# Why some devices can receive notification from firebase, but another devices can't receive

Tags: android, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I tried use three devices (two MI phone (one is Android 4.4.2,the other is Android 4.4.4)and one android emulator(Android 6.0)).

The problem is ,when i use firebase to send notification to device ,the Android 4.4.4 device always can receive the notification. But, the 4.4.2 device and the 6.0 emulator always can't receive it.

And i also tried use the token to sent notification to the designated equipment one by one. As a result, the 4.4.4 can receive ,but the 4.4.2 and the 6.0 can't receive the notification

All the test is under the some network and the some time

Comment: Hello Willpon. I am having the same prob with an Android 4.4.2. Have you had any progress with this prob? All the best

Comment: @Redjan Ymeraj Hi friend, i still not find the reason of the prob,but I think may be related to Google's servers.It has led to frequent failure of pushing  notification.Because i tried the Alibaba's notification push service ,It has never been missed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I solve by uninstall the application completely the install as new and now working good